# Angular Gantt (error: plumb.detach is not a function)

Tags: angularjs, jsplumb, gantt-chart

In my application I have used angular-gantt component. When I draw a new dependencies I've this error

```
angular.js:12808 TypeError: this.manager.plumb.detach is not a function
at Dependency.model.disconnect (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt-plugins.js:2676:44)
at DependenciesManager.removeDependency (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt-plugins.js:2321:39)
at DependenciesManager.refresh (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt-plugins.js:2617:30)
at Object.refresh (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt.js:4139:35)
at GanttApi.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9001/roadmaps/gantt/roadmapgantt.js:94:24)
at http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt.js:117:33
at Scope.$emit (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16634:33)
at Object.feature.raise.(anonymous function) [as add] (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt.js:213:42)
at root.jsPlumbInstance.createConnection (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/angular-gantt/assets/angular-gantt-plugins.js:2092:57)
at root.jsPlumbInstance.fire (http://localhost:9001/bower_components/jsplumb/dist/js/jsplumb.js:2884:64)
```

This below is the data object that I use
[image]

The error is shown when I  draw a dependecies between task.
Here the Gantt options

```
$scope.options = {
        columns: [
            'model.taskId', 
            'model.activity', 
            'model.details', 
            'model.comments'
        ],
        columnsHeaders: {
            'model.taskId': 'ID', 
            'model.activity': 'Activity', 
            'model.details': 'Detail', 
            'model.comments': 'Comments'
        },
        columnContents: {
            'model.comments': '<span class="fa fa-comment-o fa-lg" role="button" ng-click="scope.showComments(row.model.tasks)">&nbsp;{{getValue()}}</span>',
            'model.details': '<span class="underline" role="button" ng-click="scope.taskDetails(row.model.tasks)">{{getValue()}}</span>'
        },
        fromDate: moment(null),
        toDate: undefined,
        labelsEnabled: true,
        filterRow: '',
        api: function(api){
            $scope.api = api;

            api.core.on.ready($scope, function(){
                // AL RESIZE O AL MOVE, FACCIO L'UPDATE DEL TASK
                if (api.tasks.on.moveBegin) {
                    api.tasks.on.resizeEnd($scope, addEventName('tasks.on.resize', updateTaskBeginEnd));
                    api.tasks.on.moveEnd($scope, addEventName('tasks.on.move', updateTaskBeginEnd));
                }

                api.dependencies.on.add($scope, function(newData, oldData){
                    api.dependencies.refresh(newData.task);
                });

            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: I have the same error too. Don't know how to resolve.
But it raises because of this default setting to gantt-dependencies plugin. in 'js-plumb-defaults' property.
ConnectionOverlays: [['Arrow', {location: 1, length: 12, width: 12}]]

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 solutions for this issue:

1. Add the missing `detach()` function to current one `deleteConnection()`:

   On your javscript:

   ```js
   $scope.registerApi = function(api) {
       api.core.on.rendered($scope, function(api){
           api.dependencies.on.add($scope, function (dependency) {
               if(!dependency.manager.plumb.detach){
                   dependency.manager.plumb.detach = dependency.manager.plumb.deleteConnection;
               }
            });
       });
   };
   ```

   On your HTML:

   ```html
   <div gantt data="ganttData" api="registerApi">
       <gantt-dependencies enabled="true" read-only="false" conflict-checker="true" js-plumb-defaults="{
               Endpoint: ['Dot', {radius: 4}],
               Connector: 'Flowchart',
               Overlays: [[ 'Arrow', { location: 1, width: 4, length: 8 }]]
           }"></gantt-dependencies>
   </div>
   ```
2. OR, you can use Plumb version prior to 2.4.0 like 2.3.6

I implemented the first solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error and my model is quite different. I don't think it has anything to do with the js-plumb-default.

As a quick and dirty fix that has worked for me.

I have just commented out this line

```
this.manager.plumb.detach(this.connection);
```

In my implementation there isn't a detatch function in the this.connection object when it calls plumb.disconnect.

So the documentation here - https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/removing.html

The Connection was created via the mouse by a user on an element configured via makeSource which did not have deleteEndpointsOnDetach:false set.

I think that is the error with the angular-gantt-plugins.js library. Will report back.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. Here is how I fixed it, just in case it helps someone else.
Latest version of jsPlumb (as of 2018-03-22) is 2.6.9  but on the angular-gantt project [GIT repository](https://github.com/angular-gantt/angular-gantt/) the [package.json for the demo version](https://github.com/angular-gantt/angular-gantt/blob/develop/package.json) states `^2.3.2` so I supposed it was the one used for the online demo (which is working fine).

So I downgraded jsPlump to 2.3.2 and it raises no error anymore.
Here is the config I'm using:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.3.2/js/jsplumb.min.js"></script>

<gantt-dependencies 
            enabled="true"
            read-only="false"
            js-plumb-defaults="{
                    Endpoint: ['Dot', {radius: 7}],
                    Connector: 'Flowchart'
                }">
</gantt-dependencies>
```